# Using Auto Layout to align a custom UIView to the view programatically

Tags: swift

I am trying to align a custom UIView to the center of view using auto layout but I am getting a blank screen.

Please can someone advise on where my code is incorrect?

---

**My Controller's code:**

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController{

    var margin: UILayoutGuide!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        margin = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide

        let size = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
        let sq1 = Square.init(frame: size, color: UIColor.blue)

        view.addSubview(sq1)

        sq1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sq1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        sq1.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

        sq1.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        sq1.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true


    }

}
```

---

**My Custom View's code:**

```
class Square: UIView{

    init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        makeSquare(frame: frame, colour: color)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func makeSquare(frame: CGRect, colour: UIColor){
        self.layer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.backgroundColor = colour.cgColor
    }

}
```

Comment: black screen because the default background color 'UIColor.clear' just try to change background color    `self.view.backgroundColor = .red`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a height constraint , also don't mix frame layout with auto layout you should use either of them

```
sq1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200).isActive = true
```

Also if you set leading and trailing

```
sq1.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
sq1.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

then no need for a centerX

```
sq1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

---

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    sq1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    sq1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
    sq1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.trailingAnchor, constant: -20), 
    sq1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200) 
])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer @Sh_Khan - but how about the init frame that i used for Sqaure?  That contains the height and width?

Comment: when you set constraints then the frame set is ignored and it's the meaning of this line `sq.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Answer (score 0):

After some small additions:

```
class Square: UIView {

    init(color: UIColor) {
        // The view is ignored with auto layout.
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = color
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sq = Square(color: .orange)
    sq.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(sq)

    sq.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    sq.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    // -40 to compensate for the leading and trailing.
    sq.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: -40).isActive = true
    sq.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sq.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I've taken the freedom to set the height equal to the width, as you create a square, but not sure if you want that. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
class Square: UIView {


     func setColor(colour: UIColor){
        self.backgroundColor = colour
    }

}
```

call this func in `ViewDidLoad`

```
func initView() {

      self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        margin = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide

        let sq1 = Square()

        view.addSubview(sq1)

        sq1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sq1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        sq1.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        sq1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        sq1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
          sq1.setColor( colour: UIColor.blue)

}
```

result

[image]